# in pursuit of / through a pursuit of

Tags: grammar, idioms, nuance, context

Do those expressions have some different nuance and grammatically correct?

I have seen "in pursuit of" many times but rarely seen "through a pursuit of"

which one would be more proper for the sample context:

sample: 
The Western Europeans **through a pursuit of / in pursuit of** more advanced civilizations and the wealth of the East overcame their fears of the oceans and launched their ships to the seas of Asia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`through a pursuit of` implies that something came about as a *direct result* of the pursuit.

`in pursuit of` merely indicates something happened during the pursuit and is related to it somehow.

The nuance is quite fine. These phrases are mostly interchangeable.